# How to display submenu in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, class, menu

Actually, my `sub-menu` is on `display : none`. 
I need to display the class sub-menu in jQuery.
How can do that ?

```
<li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-2292">
<a href="/photos">Photos</a><br/>
<ul class="sub-menu"><br/><li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-2296">Portrait</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

Comment: @ExperimentX Comment tu as fait pour formatter le code comme il faut ? Je n'arrive pas...

Comment: @Steffi could you please use english, I don't even know what language you are using?

Comment: French lol, sorry. How do you do to format the code like this ? Please ?

Comment: Give indentation to all code. i hit enter two times and give 5 spaces before code. also `<code></code>` works but not recommended. And wrap in backticks ` for inline code.

Comment: Ah... `<code></code>` ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: And don't put that `<br/>` tag in you `nav`, thats useless if you do your css well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.menu-item').hover(
  function () {
    $('.sub-menu').show();
  },
  function () {
    $('.sub-menu').hide();
  }
);
```

Comment: PERFECT ! I just edit the second `show()` to `hide()`. But why did you not use `mouseover(function(){ ... })` ?

Answer (score 1):

(".sub-menu").Show() - to show menu

(".sub-menu").Hide() - to hide menu

Comment: Yes, but when I mouseover on `menu-item`, `sub-menu` not showing... why ?

Comment: have you attached mouse over function with parent ?

Comment: Check out my code : `$('.menu-item').mouseover(function(){ (".sub-menu").show(); });`